# gcloud - find out number of ip's free in subnet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Is there any way I can get number of free ip's in subnet using gcloud.
Issue is, I am trying to create internal lB and it is not able to get the required ip.
Can I list the ip's in used for the subnet ?

Answer (score 1):

You can list all the IPs like this

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources --asset-types='compute.googleapis.com/Instance' \
  --query="networks/default" \
  --format=json | jq ".[].additionalAttributes.networkInterfaces[].networkIP"
```

In the query field, you can filter by networks (like here) or by location/region, but you can't filter by subnet

And you get this result

```
"10.128.0.46"
"10.129.0.5"
"10.132.0.2"
```

Then you can filter and sort as you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by guillaume is a good approach. At the moment there is no specific command to view the available IP’s in a subnet, however, I found [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/169754978) and [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140136974) feature requests asking for similar functionality. I would advise you to start them and leave a comment as you would also like to have this functionality.

You can also use the following command to know how many instances are allocated in a determined subnetwork and this will help you know if you have enough available subnets:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="networkInterfaces.subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/Your_project_id/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default" --project Your_project_id
```